# Application crash while searching using regax in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing search functionality .Actually my application crash when I click search button twich (all blue screen display).I am removing all   tag and span tag.We I remove that(replace $nbsp; and span tag ) then my application goes fine.But I need to remove this before searching can you give best method so that for doing same thing.http://jsfiddle.net/AzRcn/12/

When I search "s" all screen is blue.

```
 $('.search').on('click', function () {

        $('#scroller pre').html(function(_, html) {
            var reg = new RegExp("(<span(\s+|)[>]|[$1<]*</span>)", "g");
            return html.replace(/\&nbsp\;/g, ' ').replace(reg, '');
        });
```

Comment: web pages don't crash. What actually happens? Does the page freeze, no longer responding to input? Does the page make the browser close? Does the code melt the computer?

Comment: I don't understand..can you explain .how to remove that..?

Comment: No .Actually when I search a text "s" then on first time it work fine .on click second time it spread blue color .Please check fiddle

Comment: I checked that fiddle, clicked on Search a few times and saw that blue screen that you are refering to. Could you explain better what should happen?

Comment: Actually I am using search functionality .But When I search "s" text it show &nbsp and span tag .So I remove that while clicking the search button .But after removing it show  blue screen

Comment: If I don't remove this &nbsp; and span tag it working fine..